# SQL updating table makes first row duplicate

Tags: postgresql

I have following SQL table `data`:

```
postgres=# SELECT * from data
postgres-# ;
 a  |     b     |         c
----+-----------+-------------------
 10 | some_text | some_text
 11 | some_text | some_text
 12 | some_text | some_another_text
 13 | some_text | some_another_text
(4 rows)
```

I also have `tmp` table, which was created so I could update `data` from it:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM tmp
postgres-# ;
 a  |     b     |     c
----+-----------+-----------
 21 | some_text | some_text
 22 | some_text | some_text
(2 rows)
```

So I want to update `data` with `tmp` table with following command:

```
UPDATE data SET a = tmp.a, b = tmp.b, c = tmp.c FROM tmp WHERE data.c = 'some_another_text';
```

I am expecting following output:

```
postgres=# SELECT * from data
postgres-# ;
 a  |     b     |         c
----+-----------+-------------------
 10 | some_text | some_text
 11 | some_text | some_text
 21 | some_text | some_text
 22 | some_text | some_text
(4 rows)
```

Note that fields 3 and 4 have values of a 21 and 22 respectively.

I get following output and I don't know why or even if I am doing it correctly:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM data;
 a  |     b     |     c
----+-----------+-----------
 10 | some_text | some_text
 11 | some_text | some_text
 21 | some_text | some_text
 21 | some_text | some_text
```

Comment: You have multiple rows in `tmp`. How should postgres know which one to choose when taking the values that *all* the `c = 'some_another_text'` rows from `data` should be updated with?

Comment: Do you have any primary keys (or any other unique keys) defined on those tables? You shouldn't store duplicates to begin with.